# Internal Server Error after git clone

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, bitbucket

I am running into a Internal Server Error after a git clone.

Command:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:wewewe/are.git /var/www/html
```

before running git clone I can access a test file on the URL.

I am using root 
user.

I saw before running git clone the folders are owned by root. and now still owned by root.

How do I fix?

Additional Info: 
The file called url.com/test.php only containts

Comment: Does it work if you clone (not as root) in a temporary folder?

Answer (score 0):

If the error 500 was *during* the clone, then it could be an issue on the BitBucket side (like a [corrupted repo](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/3401/cant-clone-a-repo-abort-http-error-500), or some downtime problem)

But if the error occurs *after* the clone, when refreshing the page, then it is entirely a problem of the webapp in the "`are.git`" repo, which we don't have any knowledge of.
See for example [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/10723/internal-server-error-500-after-git-pull):

> I didn't notice a PHP Error with some function, that won't work on a destination server.

Comment: Its after git clone,  I uploaded a test file using sftp with just echo "test"; same error. I also did a git pull with another test file echo "test2"; same error.

Comment: @LJBoy Again, it depends *when* you see this error. If this is when refreshing a a page of your webapp, this is not git or bitbucket related.

Comment: its really weird cause before i ran git clone, i could access url.com/test.php. I deleted it, ran git clone. test.php is in there with <?php echo "test"; ?> and ran into the 500 error. no other changes were made.

Comment: @LJBoy Any clue in the logs of the apache or nginx server?

Comment: I found out that apache mod_rewrite wasnt able. so its fixed now.